# onTestComplete function

Tags: vbscript, action, qtp

Basically the first script runs correctly on the Web (Action 1) . This inputted information is transferred from the web to a terminal emulator (backend non QTP related). → Done

A second action is then used on the terminal emulator to complete/test information.

So in effect, there are two scripts:

- Action 1 for the web,
- Action 2 for the emulator

The script for the terminal emulator also runs fine.

So the problem is this:
I don't want to call the Action 2 until Action 1 is complete (simple I arrange the actions in order they are to fire). → Done

However, I want the Action 2 to run off the datasheet from Action 1. I don't want to have to copy all the information manually from Action 1 to Action 2. Usually this is simple, as I can use the `setRow()`, `getRow()` methods. But the Action 2 datasheet is blank (as Action 1 has all the data). I can't run the Action 2, because there are no literation to run (again the datasheet in Action 2 is blank). QTP just reverts back to Action 1, because it thinks as there are now entries on Action 2, then Action 2 is complete.

All I want to do is associate Action 2 directly with the datasheet in Action 1. I don't want to simply extend the code to Action 1, because users will be moving consistently between Action 1 and Action 2.
So in a nut shell, is there

- a code to copy all datasheet contents from Action 1 to Action 2 (but do this only once, not on every iteration) so that Action two can run on what ever row I choose from?
- a simple way to associate the code of Action 2 to the Datasheet data of Action 1?
- a way to use a library function file rather than action to run the datasheet information associated with  Action 1?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Datatable.ImportSheet`  and programmatically import your test data.

Please note that, you will have to change your current row for every iteration. It should be on the start of your test... Something like

```
If DataTable.GetRowCount > DataTable.GetCurrentRow Then
    DataTable.SetCurrentRow = DataTable.GetCurrentRow + 1 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I used similar to the above. Using the datatable.getCurrentRow method allowed me to access the correct row on the second spreadsheet